Unstable work of python's GUI automation with game
I'm trying to make a script for auto-moving of items in Reign of Guilds inventory, but I've forced problem.
My script for moving an item:
pg.mouseDown(button='left')
time.sleep(0.1)
pg.move(x,y)
time.sleep(0.1)
pg.mouseUp(button='left')

But randomly game may miss LMB downing.
I've tried few alternative this for doing these work (pydirectinput, winapi), but it doesn't help.
